# Pattern matching on algebraic data types

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, algebraic-data-types

This is an open question but I never managed to find a solution that pleases me.

Let's say I have this algebraic data type :

```
type t = A of int | B of float | C of string
```

Now, let's say I want to write a `compare` function - because I want to put my values in a `Map`, for example - I'd write it like this :

```
let compare t1 t2 =
  match t1, t2 with
    | A x, A y -> compare x y
    | A _, _ -> -1
    | _, A _ -> 1
    | B x, B y -> compare x y
    | B _, _ -> -1
    | _, B _ -> 1
    | C x, C y (* or _ *) -> compare x y
```

Or I could write it like this :

```
let compare t1 t2 = 
  match t1, t2 with
    | A x, A y -> compare x y
    | B y, B x -> compare x y
    | C x, C y -> compare x y
    | A _, _
    | B _, C _ -> -1
    | _ -> 1
```

If I'm not wrong, saying that `n` is the number of constructors, the first `compare` will have `3 * (n - 1) + 1` cases and the second one will have `n + ((n - 2) * (n - 1)) / 2 + 2` cases.

This is pretty unsatisfying since :

- `n = 3` (our case) : 7 or 6 cases
- `n = 4` : 10 or 8 cases
- `n = 5` : 13 or 13 cases

It grows pretty fast.

So, I was wondering, do you do it like I do or do you use another method ?

Or, even better, is there the possibility of doing something like

```
let compare t1 t2 =
  match t1, t2 with
    | c1 x, c2 y -> 
      let c = compare c1 c2 in
      if c = 0 then compare x y else c
```

Or,

```
let compare (c1 x) (c2 y) = 
  let c = compare c1 c2 in
  if c = 0 then compare x y else c
```

Edit : added a compare if the two constructors are equal for señor Drup ([from Guadalup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=193RrdkZsjs) ;-P)

Comment: Except your comparison function is wrong, since it will say that `A 1` and `A 2` are equals.

Comment: Yes, but this won't be a problem, don't worry for that. "wrong" is just a point of view ;-)  I edited my question to please you ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of alternatives. First, you can use the `Obj` module to compare the representations directly (though that is obviously implementation-dependent):

```
type t = A of int | B of float | C of string

let compare_t a b =
  match (a, b) with
  | A x, A y -> compare x y
  | B x, B y -> compare x y
  | C x, C y -> compare x y
  | _ -> compare (Obj.tag (Obj.repr a)) (Obj.tag (Obj.repr b))
```

If you want it to be more portable, you can write (or generate) a function that gives you the numeric tag. As it turns out, the current OCaml compiler seems to be looking for that and appears to be capable of eliding the underlying function call.

```
let tag_of_t = function
  | A _ -> 0
  | B _ -> 1
  | C _ -> 2

let compare_t a b =
  match (a, b) with
  | A x, A y -> compare x y
  | B x, B y -> compare x y
  | C x, C y -> compare x y
  | _ -> compare (tag_of_t a) (tag_of_t b)
```

You still have to deal with linear growth, just not quadratic growth.

Comment: I would really discourage the first version. It's unsafe and it's not even faster.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [ppx_deriving](https://github.com/whitequark/ppx_deriving) to generate this function.

The following will create a function `compare : t -> t -> int` that does the right thing:

```
type t = A of int | B of float | C of string [@@deriving ord]
```

If you are curious, or cannot use `ppx_deriving`, here is the generated code, which uses a similar strategy as Reimer's solution.

```
% utop -require ppx_deriving.std -dsource
utop # type t = A of int | B of float | C of string [@@deriving ord];;
type t = | A of int | B of float | C of string [@@deriving ord]
let rec (compare : t -> t -> Ppx_deriving_runtime.int) =
  ((let open! Ppx_deriving_runtime in
      fun lhs  ->
        fun rhs  ->
          match (lhs, rhs) with
          | (A lhs0,A rhs0) -> Pervasives.compare lhs0 rhs0
          | (B lhs0,B rhs0) -> Pervasives.compare lhs0 rhs0
          | (C lhs0,C rhs0) -> Pervasives.compare lhs0 rhs0
          | _ ->
              let to_int = function
              | A _ -> 0
              | B _ -> 1
              | C _ -> 2
              in
              Pervasives.compare (to_int lhs) (to_int rhs))
  [@ocaml.warning "-A"]) ;;
type t = A of int | B of float | C of string
val compare : t -> t -> int = <fun>
```

Comment: I can't, sadly, accept two answers but yours was really good too. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In case you only need compare for using the `Map.Make` functor, i.e. you do not care about the specific order, you can use the built-in compare. In particular it works for the type given in your example:

```
let compare t1 t2 = compare t1 t2
```

If some, but not all of your cases are outside of the scope for the built-in compare (for example they are of function type), you can still treat the remaining cases in O(1) code size. Example:

```
type t = A of int -> int | B of float | C of string

let compare t1 t2 = match t1,t2 with
| A f1, A f2 -> ...
| A _, _ -> -1
| _, A _ -> 1
| _, _ -> compare t1 t2
```

If all that fails, there is still the option of doing meta-programming (for example through camlp5) to automatically create an otherwise longish compare. I have done that in the past, because otherwise the order of e.g.

```
type three = Zero | One | Two
```

is unspecified (`Pervasives.compare` is only specified to be *some* total order) and I wanted the natural order.

Comment: As you can see, I already know about `Pervasives.compare` but I wanted to do something more specific, hence my question. The second part of your answer can be linked to Etienne's one, no ?

Comment: Actually, it is not clear from your question that you are aware that `Pervasives.compare` works on user-defined types just as well as on built-in types. Especially as you only give `Map` as a use case. As my answer is based on a misunderstanding, I am going to delete it in due time.

Comment: No, don't delete it, it's a good answer for those who just need if they don't mind the ordering. ;-)